# Update one ROW only on table

Tags: python, mysql

Please, I want when I select Car_number the row corresponding change, but when the code executes all data (all rows change).

```
self.cur.execute('''
  UPDATE car_info 
  SET car_number=%s,owner_company=%s,branch=%s,service_mode=%s,shaceh_number=%s,motor_number=%s,fuel_type=%s,car_type=%s,car_model=%s,car_load=%s,car_weight=%s,car_shape=%s,car_color=%s
  ''',(car_number, owner_company, branch, service_mode, shaceh_number, motor_number, fuel_type, car_type, car_model,car_load, car_wight, car_shape, car_color)
)

self.db.commit()
```

Comment: So, why not add a condition to that `UPDATE` query like documented?

Answer (score 0):

To restrict the UPDATE to affect one specific row you must use a WHERE statement. The WHERE must refer to an indexed column. In most cases this would be a UNQIUE KEY which is used to identify a specific row.

If, in your case, the unique index is the car_number then you would use something like:

```
UPDATE car_info SET XXXX WHERE car_number=YYYY
```

This will then limit your UPDATE query to the single row where car_number equals YYYY

Comment: Thank you, I already did, and here is the result : 

python.exe :   File "index.py", line 159
Au niveau de ligne : 1 Caractère : 7
+ python <<<<  index.py
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (  File "index.py", line 159:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
    WHERE car_number = % s
        
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Could you share the code you are using now you have the WHERE statement in place.

Comment: self.cur.execute('''
  UPDATE car_info 
  SET car_number=%s,owner_company=%s,branch=%s,service_mode=%s,shaceh_number=%s,motor_number=%s,fuel_type=%s,car_type=%s,car_model=%s,car_load=%s,car_weight=%s,car_shape=%s,car_color=%s
  ''',(car_number, owner_company, branch, service_mode, shaceh_number, motor_number, fuel_type, car_type, car_model,car_load, car_wight, car_shape, car_color)
WHERE car_number=%s)

Comment: And I tryed : self.cur.execute('''
  UPDATE car_info 
  SET car_number=%s,owner_company=%s,branch=%s,service_mode=%s,shaceh_number=%s,motor_number=%s,fuel_type=%s,car_type=%s,car_model=%s,car_load=%s,car_weight=%s,car_shape=%s,car_color=%s
  WHERE car_number=%s ''',(car_number, owner_company, branch, service_mode, shaceh_number, motor_number, fuel_type, car_type, car_model,car_load, car_wight, car_shape, car_color)
)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are actually looking to add a `WHERE` clause to your query to select the relevant record to update. This also implies that you need to order the bind values differently:

```
self.cur.execute('''
    UPDATE car_info SET
        owner_company=%s,
        branch=%s,
        service_mode=%s,
        shaceh_number=%s,
        motor_number=%s,
        fuel_type=%s,
        car_type=%s,
        car_model=%s,
        car_load=%s,
        car_weight=%s,
        car_shape=%s,
        car_color=%s 
    WHERE car_number=%s''',
    (
        owner_company, 
        branch, 
        service_mode, 
        shaceh_number, 
        motor_number, 
        fuel_type, 
        car_type, 
        car_model,
        car_load, 
        car_weight, 
        car_shape, 
        car_color,
        car_number
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work

    
 .........   
"Not enough parameters for the SQL statement") mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement

Comment: @Med: just updated my answer by fixing a few typos... Is it working better now?